# What are the differences between security mode="Transport" and security mode="TransportCredentialOnly"

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

What are the differences between `security mode="Transport"` and `security mode="TransportCredentialOnly"` when I use it with `BasicHttpBinding` and setup ssl in ISS 7.0?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Check here:
http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2006/07/31/890.aspx
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx

`Transport` seems to require HTTPS to encrypt credentials and throws an exception if there is no SSL. `TransportCredentialOnly` will send the credentials in plain text and unencrypted and is recommended for testing ONLY!

Good Luck!!

Comment: I still get an error `SOAP Header Missing` when using `TransportCredentialOnly`. I've specified the `ClientCredentials` and the request needs to be sent over http but not luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

With TransportCredentialOnly security mode, the underlying secure transport layer (usually TLS/SSL) provides the integrity and confidentiality protection for the communication, while SOAP messaging layer handles transporting the client credentials in the SOAP message.

In other words, TransportCredentialOnly security mode passes the user credentials in the SOAP message without encrypting or signing the SOAP message, and the underlying transport connection (typically TLS/SSL) needs to ensure that the message contents cannot be seen or altered by a third-party.